# How to avoid type conversion for partial matches on number based columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am working with a legacy database and using Spring data JPA for repository access. One of the tables has an id column of number data type but the requirement is to be able to perform a partial match using a wild card character. So 12 should match 1234. If I am writing native query, I can do

`select * from table where id like 12%`

but when using Spring JPA Criteria API that provides type safety, I have to do a type conversion before I could use a like operator

```
cb.like(root.get(SomeEntity_.id).as(String.class), str + "%")
```

Notice that I have to add the **.as(String.class)** to be able to perform a string match using `like` operator. This results in a data type conversion and the query is not able to benefit from id index

`cast(table0_1_.id as varchar(255)) like ?`

Is there a way to perform the like match for this number based column without having to perform the type conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to point out that applying a `LIKE` operation against a numeric data type can have unpredictable results, see [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715407(v=vs.85).aspx) for a warning for SQL Server.

The other thing to keep in mind is that sometimes the database performs in-place coercion of values when the data-types differ or when a particular operation implies specific data type requirements.

So even though you write `id LIKE 12%`, what proof do you have that internally that isn't being coerced to `CAST(id as VARCHAR(255)) LIKE '12%'`?

But to specifically answer your question, no the JPA `CriteriaBuilder` class explicitly shows that when you wish to use a `like()` operation, the Expression *must* be of `String` data-type.  So you either have to cast it as your post illustrates or make sure the column is already of said type.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for reference.